# Fastest method for evaluating the limit of the sign of a polynomial

Tags: computational-geometry, polynomials

Consider a multivariate polynomial $f(x) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with maximum degree $d$.  Following the linear symbolic perturbation scheme described in [Seidel 1998](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-57785-8_127.pdf), I want to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \textrm{sign}~ f(x + \epsilon y)$$

for some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  This limit is given by the lowest degree nonzero coefficient of the polynomial

$$g(\epsilon) = f(x + \epsilon y)$$

If the polynomial is given as an add/multiply expression DAG of size $m$, we can evaluate $f_i(x+ty)$ for each node $f_i$ of the expression DAG, which takes at most $O(m(d+1)^2)$ using naive polynomial multiplication (and probably less in practice since most nodes will have lower degree).

Alternatively (as noted in the paper), we could evaluate $g(\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon = 0, \ldots, n-1$ and use polynomial interpolation to recover the coefficients.  This takes time $O(m(d+1)+h(d))$ where $h(d)$ is the time required for polynomial interpolation.

**Question**: Is there a faster method?  In particular, is $O(m(d+1))$ possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was writing the question, I realized that in fact *both* of the given schemes achieve $O(m(d+1))$.  This is because we always have $m \ge d$.  In the expression tree scheme, the cost of quadratic polynomial multiplication at higher nodes in the tree can be amortized to lower nodes.  In the polynomial interpolation scheme, at worst $h(d) = O(d^2)$ by precomputing the necessary matrices, and $O(m(d+1)+d^2) = O(m(d+1))$ since $m \ge d$.  The polynomial interpolation scheme is also nicely modular, since it works even if $f(x)$ is given as a black box.